# Difference : list.append() vs increment-equal?

Tags: python, list, append, addition

Is there a difference between :

```
lst.append(element)
```

and

```
lst += [element]
```

for me the second one looks better... but may be it is slower and possibly there are corner cases it may work differently ?

Comment: Yes there is a difference. In the first case you modify the existing object, in the second you create a new one. The difference will be important if there are any _other_ references to your original object. [EDIT: This is not true, thank you for the corrections below.]

Comment: @alaniwi `[element]` is a new list, but `lst` is still updated in-place by `+=`.

Comment: @alaniwi incorrect, both mutate the object in-place

Comment: Just tested it with `id` - I stand corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The end result of the two is the same, but `lst += [element]` goes to the trouble of building a new list `[element]` first, which is discarded after `list.__iadd__` iterates over it and adds each element to the end of `lst`. Use `append`.

Comment: On the other hand, `lst.append` goes through the expense of attribute lookup and the call operator, which is more expensive than the slot lookup used for `+=`. `append` does come out faster, but it's not a priori obvious that it would.

Comment: If you look at the byte code, `append` generates `CALL_METHOD`, but `+=` generates `INPLACE_ADD`, which still has to call `list.__iadd__` (or perform the equivalent thereof).

Comment: I'm finding that `lst += (element,)` is taking pretty similar time to `lst.append(element)` although `lst += [element]` is a bit slower.

Comment: @chepner: `INPLACE_ADD` gets to access the `sq_inplace_concat` slot directly, which is a lot less overhead than the attribute lookup involved in a method call. `+= [element]` still loses because of the expense of building `[element]`, which is more expensive than the attribute lookup overhead of `append`.